# " no known class method for selector ‘methodname’ " but my code is correct

Tags: iphone, ios, class

no known class method for selector ‘Logout’

but I have try to create a new project with same code,it is work!

Why?

do anyone can answer me?

LoginController.h

```
//
//  LoginController.h
//
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface LoginController : NSObject
+(void)Logout;

@end
```

LoginController.m

```
//
//  LoginController.m
//

#import "LoginController.h"

@implementation LoginController
+(void)Logout{
    //something here
}
@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
//
//  HomeViewController.m
//
#import "LoginController.h"
@interface HomeViewController ()

@end
```

HomeViewController.m

```
@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [LoginController Logout];

}
@end
```

Comment: Did you Product > Clean?

Comment: When you do this in a new project, did you copy and paste it as is? Or did you have to add something because of some warnings etc?

Comment: Lower case for the first letter would be a good thing for naming your methods ;)

Comment: Your code is confusing; you have shown `HomeViewController.m` twice.

Comment: And to @Larme's point, this isn't just stylistic. The ObjC runtime actually constructs method names in certain ways for KVC and ARC relies on naming for correct memory management. Naming things correctly, and with the right capitalization, matters.

Answer (score 0):

You likely didn't `#import "LoginController.h"` in `HomeViewController.m`, so the compiler doesn't know about this method. It looks like you did include it in the `.h`, but you may not have included an `#import "HomeViewController.h`" in `HomeViewController.m`

Comment: The OPs code is confusing; he has posted the implementation file twice (though content differs), so anything could be in play...